# AcceptVerbs not working in Web API Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call an Action in Web API Controller through an ajax request as follows

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/GuestPartyAPI/" + cerid,
            type: "GETAD",
            async: false,
            data: { Id: id, Name: name, NeedsHotel: needshotel_bool, TableNo: tableno, QR_CodeImage: qrcodeimage,
                AddressLabel: addresslabel, Address_1: address1, Address_2: address2, City: city, State: state,
                PostalCode: postalcode, Country: country, Email: email, Phone: phone
            },
            dataType: "json" 
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            //alert("cerid " + cerid);
            //alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
```

and the Action in the Controller is as follows

```
[AcceptVerbs("GETAD")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetGuestPartyCer(int cerid, GuestParty guestparty) 
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.GuestParties.AddObject(guestparty);
            db.SaveChanges();

            CeremonyGuestParty ceremonygp = new CeremonyGuestParty(); //create a CeremonyGuestParty entry to link ceremony and guestparty
            ceremonygp.CeremonyId = cerid;
            ceremonygp.GuestPartyId = guestparty.Id;
            db.CeremonyGuestParties.AddObject(ceremonygp);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, guestparty);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = guestparty.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

A similar Action in the same Controller is working with [AcceptVerbs("GETAC")] by a similar ajax request but not this one, not even by changing the verb "GETAD" to something else.

Here is the code 
    $.ajax({ 
    url: "/api/GuestPartyAPI/" + id,
    type: "GETAC",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json" });

Comment: Can you post the code of the working `$.ajax` call?

Comment: Here is the code                                             $.ajax({                                                             url: "/api/GuestPartyAPI/" + id,
        type: "GETAC",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });

Comment: Which browser do you use? How is your WebApiConfig routing config looks like? You may need to change your action to `GetGuestPartyCer(int id, GuestParty guestparty)` note the `int id` to match the default route.

Comment: By changing to "int id" it worked. Thanks nemesv.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the used `AcceptVerbs` but how is routing and action parameter matches work:

If an action parameter comes from a route parameter then the parameter name has to match the name of the parameter what you have defined in your route.

So If you use the default routing your ApiControllers:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

note that your route parameter is called `{id}`.

So in your action you need to use the same name `id` in order to the framework can do the matching.

Just change in your action signature `cerid` to `id` and it should work:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetGuestPartyCer(int id, GuestParty guestparty)
```